# Subreport not adding Header/summary of the Main report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a Billing report that show this information:

```
Customer: XXXX
    GROUP1

    CODE1 PRICE1 QUANTY1 TOTAL1
    CODE2 PRICE2 QUANTY2 TOTAL2
                         GROUP TOTAL

    GROUP2 

    CODE3 PRICE3 QUANTY3 TOTAL3
    CODE4 PRICE4 QUANTY4 TOTAL4
                         GROUP TOTAL    
                         GRAND TOTAL
```

Now, i want in the same report, at the end, the information presented in another way:

```
GROUP1 TOTAL1 
GROUP2 TOTAL2
       GRAN TOTAL
```

So, the final report is:

```
Customer: XXXX


    GROUP1

    CODE1 PRICE1 QUANTY1 TOTAL1
    CODE2 PRICE2 QUANTY2 TOTAL2
                         GROUP TOTAL

    GROUP2 

    CODE3 PRICE3 QUANTY3 TOTAL3
    CODE4 PRICE4 QUANTY4 TOTAL4
                         GROUP TOTAL    
                         GRAND TOTAL 

GROUP1 TOTAL1 
GROUP2 TOTAL2
       GRAN TOTAL
```

So, for this, i made a Subreport. The problem is, if i put this in the Summary Band, if this report make another page, The header, page count, etc won't appear. Only the subreport.
If i put this in a New Detail band,  puts in the middle of the Band Group. It groups and displays it all wrong.

I just want this in the end, and if it add pages to add the header and summary.

Where should it be?

Comment: You can use the "Report Groups" to group by the results?

Comment: The report already have groups. But the subreport is included in this group and I don't want that.